# Declaring variables using an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I came across this code in JS Novice to Ninja.

```
const form = document.getElementsByTagname('form')[0];

const [input,button] = form.elements;
```

this create a const called input mapped to the value of the form[0]
and another const called button mapped to form[1]

is this:

```
 const [input,button] = form.elements;
```

the same as:

```
const input = form.elements[0];
const button = form.elements[1];
```

Is that just some shorthand I've never come across? If so can someone tell me what it's called? Or am I misunderstanding what is happening here.

Comment: It's called *destructuring*, in this case *destructuring assignment*. The syntax on the left matches the structure of the object on the right.

Comment: [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/4642212), [Expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const [input,button] = form.elements;`

would actually be the same as

```
const input = form.elements[0];
const button = form.elements[1];
```

This is called destructuring and it can also be used for objects.

`const {value} = someObject;`
would be the same as `const value = someObject.value;`